# Testing route navigation without an outlet in Angular

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-testing

I am writing a spec for an Angular component that displays a button that will navigate to another page. The component makes use of `Router::navigate()` but does not itself have a router outlet. A parent component has the outlet. In my spec, the test should confirm that clicking on the button routes to the correct path.

My current (broken) spec tries to use `RouterTestingModule` to provide a route to a `DummyComponent`. When the button is clicked in the spec I get the following error:

`'Unhandled Promise rejection:', 'Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DummyComponent'', '; Zone:', 'angular', '; Task:', 'Promise.then', '; Value:', Error{__zone_symbol__error: Error{originalStack: 'Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'DummyComponent'`

Obviously I am approaching this problem in the wrong manner. What is the correct way to test router navigation when the component does not have a router outlet?

The component (pseudo-code):

```
@Component({
    template: `
        Go to the <button (click)="nextPage">next page</button>
    `
})
export class ExampleComponent {
    public myId = 5;

    constructor(private _router: Router);

    public nextPage(): void {
        this._router.navigate(['/example', this.myId]);
    }
}
```

The spec. This does not work:

```
const FAKE_ID = 999;

describe('ExampleComponent Test', () => {
    let exampleComponent: ExampleComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ExampleComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ DummyComponent ],
            imports: [
                RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
                    { path: 'example/:id', component: DummyComponent }
                ]);
            ]
        });

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(exampleComponent);
        exampleComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should route to example/:id', inject([Router, Location], (router: Router, location: Location) => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        exampleComponent.myId = FAKE_ID;

        const LINK_BUTTON = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('button'));
        LINK_BUTTON.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));
        expect(location.path()).toEqual('/example/' + FAKE_ID);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be an outlet (`<router-outlet>`) for the `DummyComponent`. If the `DummyComponent` is a route being navigated to from the `ExampleComponent`, then the `ExampleComponent` should have the outlet. You also also need to add the `ExampleComponent` to the declarations`

```
@Component({
  tempalte: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <button (click)="nextPage">next page</button>
  `
})
class ExampleComponent{}

declarations: [ ExampleComponent, DummyComponent ]
```

If you want to avoid having to set up this infrastructure just to test the route being navigated to, the better option might be to just mock the `Router`, and just check that the `navigate` method is called with the correct path.

```
beforeEach(()=>{
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      {
        provide: Router,
        useValue: { navigate: jasmine.createSpy('navigate') }
      }
    ]
  })
})
```

With this, you don't need to configure an routing at all, as you're using a fake `Router`. Then in your test

```
it('should route to example/:id', inject([Router], (router: Router) => {
  expect(router.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(['/example', FAKE_ID]);
});
```